# kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a

Tags: kubernetes, fedora, kubelet

I am making test Cluster following this instructions:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config/
and

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/flannel_multi_node_cluster/
unfortunately when I check my nodes following occurs:

```html
kubectl get no
NAME                        STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
pccshost2.lan.proficom.de   NotReady   <none>    19h       v1.10.3
pccshost3.lan.proficom.de   NotReady   <none>    19h       v1.10.3
```

so far as I get this problem is connected with not working kubelet.service on master-node:

```html
systemctl status kubelet.service

kubelet.service - Kubernetes Kubelet Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-03-06 10:38:30 CET; 32min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
  Process: 14057 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR $KUBE_LOG_LEVEL $KUBELET_API_SERVER $KUBELET_ADDRESS $KUBELET_PORT $KUBELET_HOSTNAME $KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV $KU>
 Main PID: 14057 (code=exited, status=255)
      CPU: 271ms

Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Consumed 271ms CPU time
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes Kubelet Server.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Consumed 271ms CPU time
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 06 10:38:30 pccshost1.lan.proficom.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Kubernetes Kubelet Server.
```

```html
~kubectl describe node

 Normal  Starting                 9s    kubelet, pccshost2.lan.proficom.de  Starting kubelet.
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientDisk    9s    kubelet, pccshost2.lan.proficom.de  Node pccshost2.lan.proficom.de status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientMemory  9s    kubelet, pccshost2.lan.proficom.de  Node pccshost2.lan.proficom.de status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal  NodeHasNoDiskPressure    9s    kubelet, pccshost2.lan.proficom.de  Node pccshost2.lan.proficom.de status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal  NodeHasSufficientPID     9s    kubelet, pccshost2.lan.proficom.de  Node pccshost2.lan.proficom.de status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
```

can somebody give an advice what is happening here and how can I fix it? Thx

Answer (score 8):

When you install k8s cluster using `kubeadm` and install kubelet in master(Ubuntu), it creates file *"10-kubeadm.conf"* located at `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d`

```
### kubelet contents
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet
$KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS 
$KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS 
$KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS 
$KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

The value of variable `$KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS` is `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` which contains the certificate signed by CA. Now, you need to verify the validity of the certificate. If the certificate has been expired then create the certificate using **openssl** and sign it with your CA.

#### Steps to verify the certificate

1. Copy the value `client-certificate-data`.
2. Decode the certificate ( echo -n "copied_certificate_value" | base64 --decode)
3. Save the output in a file (vi kubelet.crt)
4. Verify the validity (openssl x509 -in kubelet.crt -text -noout)

If the Vadility has expired then create a new certificate

Note: It is always safe to take backup before you start making any change
`cp -a /etc/kubernetes/ /root/`

#### Steps to generate a new certificate

```
openssl genrsa -out kubelet.key 2048
openssl req -new -key kubelet.key -subj "/CN=kubelet" -out kubelet.csr
openssl x509 -req -in kubelet.csr -CA /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key -out kubelet.crt -days 300
```

Encode the certificate files

```
cat kubelet.crt | base64
cat kubelet.key | base64
```

Copy the encoded content and update in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`.

##### Now, check the status of kubelet on master node

```
systemctl status kubelet
systemctl restart kubelet #restart kubelet
```

Comment: I am following Steps to generate a new certificate, when I issue openssl x509 -req -in kubelet.csr -CA /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key -out kubelet.crt -days 600 ......I get /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.srl No such file or directory     Any idea?

Comment: @eliassal It seems that an additional parameter `-CAcreateserial` is needed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357451/why-does-signing-a-certificate-require-cacreateserial-argument

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue, and found a solution [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54542#issuecomment-356879852).

Essentially, I had to run the following commands:

```
swapoff -a
kubeadm reset
kubeadm init
systemctl status kubelet
```

Then I simply had to follow the on-screen instructions. My setup used weave-net for the pod network, so I also had to run  `kubectl apply -f weave-net.yaml`.

Comment: you have a typo in your script, is `kubeadm init`

Comment: @IvanCarcamo thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the syntax error now.

Answer (score 4):

solved problem with kubelet adding `--fail-swap-on=false"` to 
`KUBELET_ARGS=` in Kubelet config file. But the problem with nodes stays same - status NotReady

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Could not start **kubelet** service in master node.

Running the below command fixed my problem :

> $ sudo swapoff -a
>
> $ sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service
>
> $ systemctl status kubelet

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to always check is swap  `sudo swapoff -a` especially after a reboot as that'll prevent your cluster from initializing