# Why does signing a certificate require `-CAcreateserial` argument?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

For example,

```bash
openssl x509 \
    -req -sha256 \
    -days "365" \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -CA "ca.crt" -CAkey "ca.key" -passin "pass:abcd" \
    -in "csr.csr" -extfile "ext.ext" \
    -out "c.crt";
```

It also creates a file `ca.srl` which contains signed certificate's serial.

The above won't work if `-CAcreateserial` argument is absent and outputs an error:

```
/test/ca.srl: No such file or directory
140413509251520:error:06067099:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters:different parameters:../crypto/evp/p_lib.c:93:
140413509251520:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72:fopen('/test/ca.srl','r')
140413509251520:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79:
```

Isn't that argument used to output a file with a serial which is possible to get via a command below anyways?

```bash
openssl x509 \
    -in "c.crt" \
    -noout \
    -serial;
```

What's the point? Why does it not create the file internally if required, but saves it on a storage?

Comment: I am using OpenSSL 3.0.3 on Windows. When I use `openssl x509 -req -CAcreateserial ...` then a `.srl` file is not generated and it works fine without `-CAcreateserial` option. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-x509.html#CAserial-filename) states: *If the -CA option is specified and neither <-CAserial> or <-CAcreateserial> is given and the default serial number file does not exist, a random number is generated; **this is the recommended practice**.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit there was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163254/23715), which caused `-CAcreateserial` to be ignored. But, as you've said, it should not be needed since OpenSSL 3.x in many cases anyway.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `-serial` option of your second command just outputs the serial number of an existing certificate. But when you're signing a certificate the CA needs to generate a unique serial number for each certificate, and until it does that, there's no serial number for `-serial` to output yet.

Since the serial number for each certificate needs to be unique for each issuer, an issuer needs to keep track of which serial numbers it has used before, to make sure it doesn't reuse any. OpenSSL gives you a simple way to keep track of this using a serial number file. When you specify `-CAcreateserial`, it'll assign the serial number `01` to the signed certificate, and then create this serial number file with the next serial number (`02`) in it. On future signing operations, you should be using `-CAserial` with the name of that file, and not `-CAcreateserial`, and OpenSSL will increment the value in that file for each certificate signed. In this way, you can sign a bunch of certificates with one issuer certificate, and all their serial numbers will be unique.

If you're using multiple issuer certificates, then you can use a separate serial number file for each one.

Note that while this approach works, it's unsuitable for production use, as there are [some problems with using strictly sequentially increasing certificate serial numbers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/257/unpredictability-of-x-509-serial-numbers).

Comment: Interesting what will happen on `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` serial. Will it overflow to zeroes?

Comment: @F8ER: If you generated 1,000,000,000 certificates every second, and you started generating them at the Big Bang, you'd have about 2^88 certificates by now. The number you quoted is 2^160 - 1. If you're starting at 1, you don't have to worry about overflowing a number like that.

Comment: Isn't a serial purely random which might be the maximum value at the very start?

Comment: It *can* be a random number (and I believe if you combine `-CAcreateserial` with `-CA`, then it will be), but even if it's purely random the odds of it being even remotely near the maximum are literally astronomical. I'm not sure what range OpenSSL uses to calculate the random number, here, but if the most significant bit is zero and all the rest of the bits are 1, for example, you'll still have 2^159 values remaining. If you're worried about it, just verify the number that was generated.

Comment: It's probably worth to notice that `-CAcreateserial` is ignored if a serial file exists.

Comment: Found related lines in sources, but haven't found the `maximum` value, yet: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a28d06f3e9cbc5594c7985c99a0c6bac5261ae67/crypto/bn/bn_rand.c#L23 <- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/22040fb790c854cefb04bed98ed38ea6357daf83/apps/x509.c#L721.

Comment: If I use my certificate only for local development, it should be no problem to always use `-CAcreateserial`, or not?

Comment: There is also a quick way to to set up default ca.srl so you don't have to bother with CAserial/CAcreateserial. echo "00" > ca.srl This way openssl x509 will pick this file by default and use it to track serial generated by the next signing operation.

Comment: @Crowman: Don't be ridiculous. We wouldn't want people thinking we were new at this! We're starting at 1000. What NOW, smart guy? (I'm totally kidding. Fantastic answer! XD )

Answer (score 3):

In regards to the awesome [@Crowman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66357989/5113030)'s answer, I created a [script](https://gist.github.com/artshade/ef94b28b09f5828e41e555acac60c9cf) which might demonstrate the behavior:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# -------------------------- #
# User variables             #
# -------------------------- #

certificateAuthorityName="certificate_authority";
certificateAuthorityPrivateKeyPassword="";

certificateName="certificate";
certificateTestPostfix="_test";

# -------------------------- #
# Variables                  #
# -------------------------- #

stdout='/dev/null';
stderr='/dev/null';
certificateAuthorityFilepath="$( pwd )/${certificateAuthorityName}";
certificateFilepath="$( pwd )/${certificateName}";

# -------------------------- #
# Functions                  #
# -------------------------- #

function OR
{
    declare i;

    for (( i=0; i < "$1"; i++ ));
    do
        printf '%s' "$2";
    done;
}

function SignedCertificateCreate
{
    declare createSerial_l="-CAserial ${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.srl";

    if [ "$1" = "1" ];
    then
        rm "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.srl" > "/dev/null" 2>&1;
        createSerial_l='-CAcreateserial';
    fi

    if ! openssl x509 \
        -req -sha256 \
        -days "365" \
        $createSerial_l \
        -CA "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.crt" -CAkey "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.key" -passin "pass:${certificateAuthorityPrivateKeyPassword}" \
        -in "${certificateFilepath}.csr" -extfile "${certificateFilepath}.ext" \
        -out "${certificateFilepath}${certificateTestPostfix}.crt" \
        > "$stdout" 2> "$stderr";
    then
        printf $'Couldn\'t create a certificate\n';

        return 1;
    fi
}

function SignedCertificatesCreate
{
    declare loops_l="1";

    if [ "$1" != "" ];
    then
        loops_l="$1";
    fi

    declare i;

    for (( i=0; i < "$loops_l"; i++ ));
    do
        if ! SignedCertificateCreate "$2";
        then
            return 1;
        fi
    done
}

function ReadCertificateSerialFromFile
{
    cat "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.srl" 2> "$stderr";
}

# -------------------------- #
# Methods                    #
# -------------------------- #

function Help
{
    echo
    printf ' Description: OpenSSL serial generation test\n\n';
    printf ' Additional arguments:\n\n';
    printf '   -d - Enable certain output for debugging\n';
    printf '   -h - Help message\n\n';
}

function Main
{
    if [[ "$1" == *"h"* ]];
    then
        Help;
        exit 0;
    fi

    if [[ "$1" == *"d"* ]];
    then
        stdout='/dev/stdout';
        stderr='/dev/stderr';
    fi

    if [ ! -f "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.key" ];
    then
        printf $'There\'s no Certificate Authority private key: %s\n' "${certificateAuthorityFilepath}.key";
        exit 1;
    fi

    if [ "$certificateAuthorityPrivateKeyPassword" = "" ];
    then
        echo
        read -s -p " [ ? ] Certificate Authority Private Key Password: " certificateAuthorityPrivateKeyPassword;
        echo
    fi

    printf '\n  %s \n' "$( OR 80 "-" )";
    printf ' | %35s | ' 'A new {serial #1} generated';
    SignedCertificateCreate 1 || exit 2;
    printf '%40s |\n' "$( ReadCertificateSerialFromFile )"
    printf ' | %35s | ' 'A new {serial #2} generated';
    SignedCertificateCreate 1 || exit 3;
    printf '%40s |\n' "$( ReadCertificateSerialFromFile )"
    printf ' | %35s | ' 'Used the same {serial #2} 5 times';
    SignedCertificatesCreate 5 || exit 4;
    printf '%40s |\n' "$( ReadCertificateSerialFromFile )"
    printf ' | %35s | ' 'Used the same {serial #2} 256 times';
    SignedCertificatesCreate 256 || exit 5;
    printf '%40s |\n' "$( ReadCertificateSerialFromFile )"
    printf '  %s \n\n' "$( OR 80 "-" )";
}

# -------------------------- #
# Main                       #
# -------------------------- #

Main "$@";
```

A possible script's result:

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |         A new {serial #1} generated | 310BD94F916BDF47913249966B85A9F7771D746A |
 |         A new {serial #2} generated | 0AC91627E4E99612D3CC7D99BB9793445CEDB36B |
 |   Used the same {serial #2} 5 times | 0AC91627E4E99612D3CC7D99BB9793445CEDB370 |
 | Used the same {serial #2} 256 times | 0AC91627E4E99612D3CC7D99BB9793445CEDB470 |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just to clarify, the `{serial #2}` output differs (the very endings):

- ...`B36B`<sub>hex</sub> or `45931`<sub>dec</sub> (0);
- ...`B370`<sub>hex</sub> or `45936`<sub>dec</sub> (+5);
- ...`B470`<sub>hex</sub> or `46192`<sub>dec</sub> (+256).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the bash code. Regarding 5 and 256 time, do you print out just one of generated serial value in SRL file in 5 and 256 time repetition?

Comment: I am sorry, @CloudCho, but is it possible to rephrase the question or add more details?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. My question are:  (1) Do you run serial number generation for 5 and 256 times? (2) If yes, how come you have only one serial number in the table?

Comment: Just in case, @CloudCho, added more details to the question. The serials of `{serial #2}` differ but are directly related since the same `*.srl` file is specified in 38 line of the script.

Comment: @Faither...thanks for explanation, but it looks like I need to run your BASH script to understand. Have you looked into source code of OpenSSL regarding the limit of randomness or put an Issue in GitHub repository?

Comment: I believe more detailed description of "limit of randomness" will help, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Limit of randomness meant that all (generated) their serial numbers won't be (that) unique. Isn't this your main problem when you run 5 or 256 times?